# ggplot2 density with multiple groups and trim=TRUE: density does not go to 0?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggvis, density-plot

I am plotting in `ggplot2` densities for multiple groups that each have a different support. For this reason, I would like the density lines to stop at the min/max of the respective groups, to convey visually the difference in supports. I can do this with `ggvis`, see:

[image]

However, I am not able to do this nicely with `geom_density()`:

- By default (`trim=FALSE`) `geom_density()` will extend the lines of the density at 0, so that all densities overlap at 0, makes difficult to compare support
- Setting `trim=TRUE`, `geom_density()` does not extend the lines outside of the respective support, yet will trim the lines even over the y axis.

How can I mimic the `ggvis` plot with `ggplot::geom_density`?

#### Code

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggvis)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggvis'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     resolution
library(patchwork)

df <- tibble(x1=truncnorm::rtruncnorm(500, -1, 1),
           x2=truncnorm::rtruncnorm(500, -1.5, 1.5),
           x3=rnorm(500)) %>% 
  gather(variable, value, everything())


pl_gg_trim <- ggplot(df, aes(x=value, color=variable))+
  geom_density(trim=TRUE) +
  ggtitle("trim=TRUE: lines don't go to 0")
pl_gg_notrim <- ggplot(df, aes(x=value, color=variable))+
  geom_density()+
  ggtitle("trim=FALSE: hard to understand support of values")



pl_ggvis <- ggvis(df, ~value, fill = ~variable) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  layer_densities()

#does not work with reprex: pl_ggvis

pl_gg_notrim/pl_gg_trim
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I'm having a hard time pinpointing what the difference between ggplot2 and ggvis is that you try to mimic. The only obvious difference I can see is that the ggvis plot has a fill and an alpha instead of a colour, but you can easily set `geom_density(aes(fill = variable), alpha = 0.3)` in ggplot2, so what is it exactly you're looking for?

Comment: well see how the second ggplot density lines are not going to 0 on the y-axis! That's my main concern here!

Comment: @Matifou did you end up finding a workaround? I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: @scottkosty not really, though see my new response below. You might want to put a bounty on this, or open a github request for a new type of `outline.type`?

Comment: @Matifou sounds good, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A workaround could be to use the base `density` function and plot that as `geom_line`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(x1=truncnorm::rtruncnorm(500, -1, 1),
             x2=truncnorm::rtruncnorm(500, -1.5, 1.5),
             x3=rnorm(500)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")

df %>%
  nest(data=value) %>% 
  mutate(fit=map(data, ~density(.$value)), results=map(fit, tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(results) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color=variable)) + 
  geom_line() +
  labs(x="value", y="density")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

With ggplot 3.3.0 (see [news](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/)), there is now a new `outline.type` argument, that controls how the strokes are plotted.

Setting `outline.type = "full"` will make the end points of the density points go to zero, at the cost however of having now a line on the x axis linking both points.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x1=truncnorm::rtruncnorm(500, -1, 1),
             x2=truncnorm::rtruncnorm(500, -1.5, 1.5),
             x3=rnorm(500)) |> 
  gather(variable, value, everything())


ggplot(df, aes(x=value, color=variable))+
  geom_density(trim=TRUE, outline.type = "full")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>